# Kubernetes - Why use dotfiles in secret volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-enterprise

The Kubernetes documentation for secrets includes a section "Use-case: Dotfiles in secret volume" which states: In order to make piece of data ‘hidden’ (ie, in a file whose name begins with a dot character), simply make that key begin with a dot. For example, when the following secret is mounted into a volume:

```
{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "dotfile-secret"
  },
  "data": {
    ".secret-file": "dmFsdWUtMg0KDQo="
  }
}
....
```

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/

I am not sure what data being hidden means and what benefit it provides.   Has anyone used this feature?  If so, would you please elaborate on what value it provides over regular secrets without dot notation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just saying you can include dotfiles in secret volumes, nothing more than that

Comment: what is "dmFsdWUtMg0KDQo=" in the line?